# Convergent series description of ratio of two bilinear forms

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have to numerically calculate the ratio of two bilinear forms:

$\frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{v^T U_1 v}{v^T U_2 v}$,

where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are unitary matrices. Both bilinear forms $x_1$ and $x_2$ are very small, the ratio however could be finite, which is why the numerical stability of this procedure is very low. However, ignoring the rules of calculus for a moment I am dreaming of a series that starts like this,

$\frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{v^T U_1 v}{v^T U_2 v} = v^T (U_1 / U_2) v + \dots $.

the vector $v$ is complex (i.e. v^T is the hermitian adjoint) and of unit length $v^T v = 1$

Is anyone aware of a series description that comes close to this?

Comment: Is the vector $v$ real or complex?

Comment: The problem is likely the magnitude of the $v$ vector, since the ratio is independent of the length of the vector.  You should lengthen it until $(x_1, x_2)$ are no longer _small_.

Comment: The vector v is complex.(also added that to the description of the problem)

Comment: The problem cannot be the length of vector v since it is of unit length (also added that to the description of the problem)